# Firefox doesn't save the web page's title as themselves

Tags: firefox

I want to save web pages, for example, the link http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/ap080406.html. In other browsers, like [Avant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avant_Browser) or [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29), the web title saves as itself (for example, for the above link, the web title save as "AP OD_ 2008 April 6 - Wisps Surrounding the Horsehead Nebula"), but in Firefox the web title saves as "ap080406". How can I save the web title's as themselves?

Answer (score 1):

The appropriately named Firefox add-on [File Title](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/file-title/) is exactly what you are looking for.